# Why Object Nil can't create?

Tags: scala

Having the error:

Object creation impossible, since member node: Option[(A, MyModule.List[A])] in MyModule.List is not defined

```html
sealed trait List[+A] {
    def node: Option[(A, List[A])]
    def isEmpty = node.isEmpty
  }
  abstract  class Cons[+A](head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]
  object Nil extends List[Nothing]

  object List {
    def empty[A] = new List[A] { def node = None }
    def cons[A](head: A, tail: List[A]) = new List[A] { def node = Some((head, tail)) }

    def apply[A](as: A*):List[A] = {
      if (as.isEmpty) Nil
      else Cons(as.head, apply(as.tail: _*))
```

In this case, how to implement?
I wonder what functions should be put in trait and what functions should be put in Company Object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is correct implementation:

```
sealed trait List[+A] {
  def node: Option[(A, List[A])]

  def isEmpty = node.isEmpty
}

case class Cons[+A](head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A] {
  override def node: Option[(A, List[A])] = Some((head, tail))
}

object Nil extends List[Nothing] {
  override def node: Option[(Nothing, List[Nothing])] = None
}

object List {
  def empty[A] = new List[A] {
    def node = None
  }

  def cons[A](head: A, tail: List[A]) = new List[A] {
    def node = Some((head, tail))
  }

  def apply[A](as: A*): List[A] = {
    if (as.isEmpty) Nil
    else Cons(as.head, apply(as.tail: _*))
  }
}
```

I see few problems here:

1) You have two implementation of cons
you can implement `cons` method simpler:

```
  def cons[A](head: A, tail: List[A]) = Cons(head, tail)
```

2) Same with `empty`

```
  def empty[A] = Nil
```

Comment: Yes, Cons and Empty implementations are duplicated.
In the object List, no new List is needed, only the new Cons and Nil are needed.Just like you added.